# Calculate the haversine nearest distance for multiple points ,using two dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to know what is the distance of the nearest place in dataframe two to each of the rows in dataframe one.(What is the nearest place in distance for each coordinates in my dataframe one)

LOOK BELOW ALL MY CODE

I have two Dataframes: (In the original DataFrame I have thousands of rows)

The DataFrame 1 called "place_locations" :*

```
|CLUSTER|     |CLIENT|     |LATITUDE|           |LENGHT|

0            X1        19.45685402  -70.68645898
1            X1        19.39320504  -70.52567322
2            X1        18.614736        -68.71711383
3            X2        18.47977644  -69.93177289
4            X2        19.76546997  -70.51085451
5            X3        18.55835346  -68.38226906
6            X3        19.79037017  -70.68748243
7            X4        19.2232559   -70.52629188
8            X4        18.42865751  -68.9703434
9            X5        19.37935119  -70.51440314
10           X5        18.68743273  -68.45068029
11           X6        19.44126162  -70.73159162
12           X6        19.6678557   -70.36758867
13           X7        18.7816069   -70.2598325
14           X8        19.48708304  -70.74375908
15           X8        18.93720371  -70.40746487
16           X9        19.299298        -69.5559162
17          X10        18.60044506  -68.41991221
18          X10        19.30702896  -69.54500792
19          X11        19.3783253   -70.618205
```

*The DataFrame 2 called "Coordinates_coords" :*

```
 | PLACE|               | LATITUDE|           | LENGHT| 
  supermarket       18.63609095 -68.39650565
   school           19.44512055 -70.66851055
   restarant        18.48377033 -69.93910793
   spa              18.46608496 -69.92713481
   supermarket      18.45646778 -69.9395694
   restaurant       18.4845644  -69.9300583
   school           18.47284417 -69.9345797
```

```
def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    
   
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6371 * c
    return km
```

```
def Top_nearest(distancia,distancias,todos = False,limit= 1.0):
    results = []
    for d in distancias:
        results.append(haversine_np(distancia[0],distancia[1],d[0],d[1]))
    results= np.array(results)
    if not todos:
        print(results.argmin())
        indexes = np.where(results < limit)
    else:
        indexes = np.where(results>= 0)
    
    return list(indexes[0]),results[indexes]
```

```
nearest_coordinates = list()

for index,row in place_locations.iterrows():
    indexes,distances=Top_nearest(row[['LATITUDE', 'LENGHT']].values,
                                     Coordinates_coords[['LATITUDE', 'LENGHT']].reset_index(drop=True).values,
                                            todos=True)
    nearest_coordinates.append(distances[0])

nearest_coordinates [:5]
```

```
place_locations['Distance_locations'] = nearest_coordinates 
place_locations
```

The results that Im getting are not the correct, there are something in the calculus that I cant identify. The Distance_location column that Im getting, dont give me the nearest distance location

Comment: Where do you actually sort the distances? It looks like you're calculating the distance against each point and then just leaving those in an array without sorting them (although you say when results >= 0, when I don't think results can be lower than 0).

Maybe do an argsort  instead of np.where and take the fIrst (or first N) values?

Answer (score 1):

I've previously posted on this. [location, distance, nearest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300859/python-location-show-distance-from-closest-other-location/63330746#63330746)

It's simplest to use a library to calculate distances.  [geopy](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/) has worked well for me

```
import geopy.distance
import pandas as pd
import io
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""CLUSTER     CLIENT     LATITUDE           LENGHT

0            X1        19.45685402  -70.68645898
1            X1        19.39320504  -70.52567322
2            X1        18.614736        -68.71711383
3            X2        18.47977644  -69.93177289
4            X2        19.76546997  -70.51085451
5            X3        18.55835346  -68.38226906
6            X3        19.79037017  -70.68748243
7            X4        19.2232559   -70.52629188
8            X4        18.42865751  -68.9703434
9            X5        19.37935119  -70.51440314
10           X5        18.68743273  -68.45068029
11           X6        19.44126162  -70.73159162
12           X6        19.6678557   -70.36758867
13           X7        18.7816069   -70.2598325
14           X8        19.48708304  -70.74375908
15           X8        18.93720371  -70.40746487
16           X9        19.299298        -69.5559162
17          X10        18.60044506  -68.41991221
18          X10        19.30702896  -69.54500792
19          X11        19.3783253   -70.618205"""), sep="\s+")

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(""" PLACE                LATITUDE            LENGHT 
  supermarket       18.63609095 -68.39650565
   school           19.44512055 -70.66851055
   restarant        18.48377033 -69.93910793
   spa              18.46608496 -69.92713481
   supermarket      18.45646778 -69.9395694
   restaurant       18.4845644  -69.9300583
   school           18.47284417 -69.9345797"""), sep="\s+")

# no need to calc distance in miles and kms,  there for reference
df3 = (df1
 .assign(foo=1)
 .merge(df2.assign(foo=1), on="foo")
 .assign(distance_km=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: 
                                      geopy.distance.geodesic(
                                          (r["LATITUDE_x"],r["LENGHT_y"]), 
                                          (r["LATITUDE_y"],r["LENGHT_y"])).km, axis=1))
 .assign(distance_miles=lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda r: 
                                      geopy.distance.geodesic(
                                          (r["LATITUDE_x"],r["LENGHT_y"]), 
                                          (r["LATITUDE_y"],r["LENGHT_y"])).miles, axis=1))

 
)

# now find nearest PLACE to a CLIENT and count
(df3.sort_values(["CLIENT","distance_km"])
 .groupby(["CLIENT"]).agg({"PLACE":"first","distance_km":"first"})
 .reset_index()
 .groupby("PLACE")["CLIENT"].count()
 .to_frame().reset_index().sort_values("CLIENT",ascending=False)
)
```

### output

```
         PLACE  CLIENT
2       school       5
3  supermarket       4
0    restarant       1
1   restaurant       1
```